# This now locked question is answerable

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How much am I expected to know as a technical student co-op?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/19283/2322)

This question is answerable with a minor edit to clarify the question is "what are expectations of coop students?" rather than "what technology should I know?"

Comment: This is now unlocked, if you'd like to make some edits.

Comment: @jmort253 http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19283/how-much-am-i-expected-to-know-as-a-student-co-op#comment47838_19283

Comment: @enderland side note, removed my half of the comments discussing its validity, if you'd like to do the same

Comment: Nice save man!!